# Excel Blank Column reading in php

Tags: php, excel

I am uploading excel in PHP using PHPExcel_IOFactory, In excel there are some columns which should be compulsory filled like B,D,I,J and more.

My need is to first change Column B, if its blank an error should occur else check column D, if blank error else check further columns.

I have written below code, but i didn't got to check one column at a time:

```
 $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
 $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet); 
 for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
    $b = $allDataInSheet[$i]["B"];
    $d = $allDataInSheet[$i]["D"];
    $i = $allDataInSheet[$i]["I"];
 }
```

There are almost 20 columns compulsory, how can i check each column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. You're using `$i` in the `for($i=2...` line, but you set it to something else inside the loop  with `$i = $allData...`.

To meet your requirements (including starting with 2nd row), this is what I would do

```
$firstK = key($allDataInSheet); //save the first key

foreach($allDataInSheet as $k => $row){
    if($k===$firstK) continue; //skip the first row

    if(empty($b = $row['B'])){
        // Error. column B is empty
    }elseif(empty($c = $row['C'])){
        // B is not empty. $b has its contents
        // however, Error: column C is empty
    }elseif(empty($i = $row['I'])){
        // B and C are not empty. $b and $c have their contents
        // however, Error: column I is empty
    ...
    }else{
        // All required columns have data
        // $b, $c ... $i ... hold the contents
    }

    //...continue processing the row. You can use variables $b, $c...
}
```

Comment: @DhawalMhatre I've added code to skip the first row and check from the 2nd. By the way your original code starts with the 3rd row (you set `$i=2` on the `for` line), not the 2nd row as you wish. Remember to select and upvote this solution if you use it.